# Pandas - iterating on column and update value

Tags: python, pandas, series

Since the tf-idf vectoriser will just crash anytime it encounters new labels, I'm trying to remove new lables from my new input. How can I update a dataframes' column's value? I'm doing:

```
def clean_unseen(dfcol, vectorizer):
    cleanedstring = ""
    for entry in dfcol:
        for word in entry.split():
            if word in vectorizer.vocabulary_:
                cleanedstring = cleanedstring + " " + word
                print(cleanedstring)
        entry = cleanedstring
        cleanedstring = ""
    return dfcol
```

Example:

```
tfifgbdf_vect= TfidfVectorizer()
s2 = pd.Series(['the cat', 'awesome xyz', 'f_g_h lol asd'])
tfifgbdf_vect.fit_transform(s2)
s3 = pd.Series(['the dog the awesome xyz', 'xyz lol asd', 'f_g_h lol aha'])
clean_unseen(s3, tfifgbdf_vect)
```

This, however, will return the original column unchanged:

```
Output: 
0    the dog the awesome xyz
1                xyz lol asd
2              f_g_h lol aha
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a single entry in a series is not an object, it is always a deep copy and not a reference, you need to change your explicitly -

```
def clean_unseen(dfcol, vectorizer):
    dfc1 = []
    cleanedstring = ""
    for entry in dfcol:
        for word in entry.split():
            if word in vectorizer.vocabulary_:
                cleanedstring = cleanedstring + " " + word
                #print(cleanedstring)
        #entry = cleanedstring
        dfc1.append(cleanedstring)
        cleanedstring = ""

    return pd.Series(dfc1)

tfifgbdf_vect= TfidfVectorizer()
s2 = pd.Series(['the cat', 'awesome xyz', 'f_g_h lol asd'])
tfifgbdf_vect.fit_transform(s2)
s3 = pd.Series(['the dog the awesome xyz', 'xyz lol asd', 'f_g_h lol aha'])
clean_unseen(s3, tfifgbdf_vect)
```